# When sending a newsletter -not with wordpress- the server has 100% cpu

Tags: posts, post-meta

When sending a newsletter (not with wordpress, but with another external newsletter campaign tool) to **3,298 recipients**, we have unique opens: **155**, the server has 100% cpu from too many httpd instances and mysql.

The dedicated machine...
CentOS Linux 6.5
Linux 2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.x86_64 on x86_64
Webmin version: 1.701
Proccessors: 4
Real memory: 15.57 GB total
Virtual memory: 4 GB total
Apache/2.2.15 (Keep Alive On)
MySQL v.5.1.73-log
PHP v.5.3.3
APC v.3.1.13
[image: APC Stats]

WordPress 3.9.2 running Bucket (http://themeforest.net/item/bucket-a-digital-magazine-style-wordpress-theme/6107209) Child theme.
Database size = 1.6 GB
wp_posts = 118999 (rows)
wp_postmeta = 1656568 (rows)

WordPress Plugins running
1.  Additional Image Sizes (zui)
2.  Contact Form 7
3.  Custom User Profile Photo
4.  Disqus Comment System
5.  Google Analytics for WordPress
6.  Newsletter Pro
7.  NextGEN Gallery by Photocrati
8.  NextScripts: Social Networks Auto-Poster
9.  P3 (Plugin Performance Profiler)
10. PixCodes
11. PixTypes
12. Post title marquee scroll
13. UBM Premium
14. Vixy YouTube Embed
15. W3 Total Cache (APC enabled)
16. Wordfence Security
17. WP-Optimize
18. Yet Another Related Posts Plugin

from **wp-confing.php**

```
/** Enable W3 Total Cache */  
define('WP_CACHE', true); // Added by W3 Total Cache  
/** Enable W3 Total Cache */  

define( 'AUTOMATIC_UPDATER_DISABLED', true );  
define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);  
define( 'DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', true );  

define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M');  
define('WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT', '512M');
```

Results from MySQLTuner script

```
MySQLTuner 1.3.0 - Major Hayden <major@mhtx.net>  
Run with '--help' for additional options and output filtering  
[OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 5.1.73-log  
[OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture  

-------- Storage Engine Statistics -------------------------------------------  
[--] Status: +CSV +InnoDB +MRG_MYISAM  
[--] Data in MyISAM tables: 442M (Tables: 25)  
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 1G (Tables: 68)  
[!!] Total fragmented tables: 61  

-------- Security Recommendations  -------------------------------------------  
[OK] All database users have passwords assigned  

-------- Performance Metrics -------------------------------------------------  
[--] Up for: 5d 21h 7m 0s (35M q [70.046 qps], 379K conn, TX: 152B, RX: 7B)  
[--] Reads / Writes: 59% / 41%  
[--] Total buffers: 5.9G global + 4.2M per thread (500 max threads)  
[OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 8.0G (51% of installed RAM)  
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (23K/35M)  
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 17% (88/500)  
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 128.0M/75.2M  
[OK] Key buffer hit rate: 99.8% (101M cached / 155K reads)  
[OK] Query cache efficiency: 46.9% (11M cached / 23M selects)  
[OK] Query cache prunes per day: 0  
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 1% (30K temp sorts / 1M sorts)  
[!!] Temporary tables created on disk: 32% (1M on disk / 4M total)  
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 99% (259 created / 379K connections)  
[!!] Table cache hit rate: 0% (96 open / 64K opened)  
[OK] Open file limit used: 0% (2/65K)  
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 99% (21M immediate / 21M locks)  
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 4.0G/1.0G  
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0  
-------- Recommendations -----------------------------------------------------  
General recommendations:  
    Run OPTIMIZE TABLE to defragment tables for better performance  
    Temporary table size is already large - reduce result set size  
    Reduce your SELECT DISTINCT queries without LIMIT clauses  
    Increase table_cache gradually to avoid file descriptor limits  
    Read this before increasing table_cache over 64:  
Variables to adjust:  
    table_cache (> 64)
```

Can someone please suggest what to look for?
Thank you!

Comment: Could you post a current complete MySQLTuner report from the WordPress you are using today?  Suggestions for improving MySQL instance performance could be provided.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have two problems, and one is simply unveiling the other.

The first problem is that the newsletter software/service is probably using unique links to track clicks and campaigns. For example, if Google Analytics tracking is enabled in a MailChimp campaign, it'll append a `utm_campaign` variable to every target URL, and a unique per-user `utm_term` variable.

This means, that every single click in your e-mail campaign is a unique URL, and your page caching plugin will probably not serve it from cache (assuming you're using a page caching plugin), but generate it from scratch, which could be causing the load. I'm not sure about W3 Total Cache, there's probably a setting or something, but here's how I ignore `utm_` variables in my Batcache configuration:

```
// Ignore get keys not used by PHP to serve cached pages.
$ignore_get_keys = array( 'utm_source', 'utm_medium', 'utm_term', 'utm_content', 'utm_campaign' );

parse_str( $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $query );
foreach ( $ignore_get_keys as $key ) {
    if ( isset( $query[ $key ] ) )
        unset( $query[ $key ] );

    if ( isset( $_GET[ $key ] ) )
        unset( $_GET[ $key ] );
}

$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] = http_build_query( $query );
```

The second problem is the fact that your 4-core 16G server dies with 155 opens. A properly configured $5 single-core 512M server can serve over 5000 requests per second, with page caching to be fair. Around 5-10 per second without caching.

So according to my *very rough* calculations, you should be able to serve a minimum of 50 requests per second without caching at all, so if 155 opens is causing massive load problems on your server, then something is clearly wrong.

Profiling is a good place to start. Get yourself an XHProf module and you can even do it on your production server. Have it e-mail and/or log requests that take longer than 1s and you'll probably spot the bottleneck pretty quickly.

After you figure out and sort the bottleneck, I also recommend you ditch Apache in favor of nginx and php 5.6 in fpm mode.

Comment: Unfortunately the problem was not resolved :(

Comment: You can follow this guide to see how to install XHProf on your production wordpress server here (Debian only) https://tech.michaelaltfield.net/2022/06/07/wordpress-xhprof/